# Identify text-based format

Tags: format

Is the data below in a well-known format, or is this a custom format invented by the generator?

> [{
>       "tmsId": "MV006574730000",
>       "rootId": "11214341",
>       "subType": "Feature Film",
>       "title": "Doctor Strange 3D",
>       "releaseYear": 2016,
>       "releaseDate": "2016-11-04",
>       "titleLang": "en",
>       "descriptionLang": "en",
>       "entityType": "Movie",
>       "genres": ["Action", "Adventure", "Fantasy"],
>       "longDescription": "Dr. Stephen Strange's (Benedict Cumberbatch) life changes after a car accident robs him of the use of his hands.
>   When traditional medicine fails him, he looks for healing, and hope,
>   in a mysterious enclave. He quickly learns that the enclave is at the
>   front line of a battle against unseen dark forces bent on destroying
>   reality. Before long, Strange is forced to choose between his life of
>   fortune and status or leave it all behind to defend the world as the
>   most powerful sorcerer in existence.",
>       "shortDescription": "Dr. Stephen Strange discovers the world of magic after meeting the Ancient One.",
>       "topCast": ["Benedict Cumberbatch", "Chiwetel Ejiofor", "Rachel McAdams"],
>       "directors": ["Scott Derrickson"],
>       "officialUrl": "http://marvel.com/doctorstrange",
>       "ratings": [{
>           "body": "Motion Picture Association of America",
>           "code": "PG-13"
>       }],

Comment: This looks like JSON, or at least a fragment of a JSON array.

Comment: Yes, it is JSON, probably from a document database like MongoDB. It should be simple to convert it to another format for your program's consumption

Comment: @TylerDurden: With a name like that, I would have expected the sample data to be about a certain other motion picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is indeed JSON format. I suppose the chunk of data you are giving us here are not the complete data. Because there missing some closing brackets. Well if you delete the last comma "," and put there these: "}]".

Then as you can see it passes validation in the jsonlint.
You can try this here: [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/)